# Codeigniter and Firebird $this->db->join with Lower support

Tags: php, codeigniter, join, firebird

This is what I am doing to get records from Firebird database using Codeigniter:

```
$columns = [
            'job.JOBID AS Id', 'job.ORDERID AS orderID', 'suburb.LONGITUDE AS Longitude', 'suburb.LATITUDE AS Latitude', 'suburb.LCNAME', 'address.TOWN', ];
        $this->db->select($columns);
        $this->db->from('WORK as job');
        $this->db->join('CUSTOMER AS customer', 'customer.CUSTOMERID = job.CUSOMERTID', 'INNER');
        $this->db->join('SALEORDER AS sorder', 'sorder.ORDERID = job.ORDERID', 'INNER');
        $this->db->join('CUSTADDRESS AS address', 'address.ADDRID = sorder.DELADDRID', 'INNER');        
        $this->db->join('WORK2 AS job2', 'job2.JOBID = job.JOBID', 'LEFT');

        // THE BELOW LINE CAUSE ERROR DUE TO LOWER
        $this->db->join('SUBURBS AS suburb', 'suburb.LCNAME = LOWER(address.TOWN)', 'LEFT');

        $query = $this->db->get();
```

The code is working fine without `LOWER` and the related `JOIN` do not work without it because the condition go false. I have let say, `suburb.LCNAME = 'blacktown'` and `address.Town = BlackTown`.

I am getting following error message,

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Warning
>   Message: ibase_query(): Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -206 Column unknown ADDRESS.TOWN At line 12, column 1
>   Filename: ibase/ibase_driver.php
>   Line Number: 129

Comment: What is $columns ??

Comment: Is there a way to get the actual query generated this way? Because I'd expect the column unknown error to be triggered either for both `LOWER(address.TOWN)` and just `address.TOWN`, or for neither, which might hint at some problem in the way the query is generated.

Comment: BTW: also consider trying `suburb.LCNAME collate unicode_ci = address.TOWN` (assuming both are character set UTF8, otherwise use the case insensitive collation for the actual character set)

Comment: before calling `get()` please do `echo` the text query - `$this->db->get_compiled_select();` and show us the real query generated before it goes to SQL server - https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html  If not now, then in future, so that FB-users with zero exposure to PHP could opinionate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the alias address and use the original table name from the following line as well as from your code.
$this->db->join('CUSTADDRESS AS address', 'address.ADDRID = sorder.DELADDRID', 'INNER');

Use Instead:
$this->db->join('CUSTADDRESS', 'CUSTADDRESS.ADDRID = sorder.DELADDRID', 'INNER');

Comment: Thankyou Zeebok, This just did a trick. I have wasted my two solid days on it. Now it worked.

Comment: @user6159419 searching for "alias" keyword in Code Igniter documentation shows it only supports aliases for selected expressions and columns, not aliases to tables, views and other relations. Though I can hardly explain this drawback, perhaps no one ever asked for it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->db->select($columns.',LOWER(address.Town) as lower_address');
 $this->db->from('WORK as job');
 $this->db->join('CUSTOMER AS customer', 'customer.CUSTOMERID = job.CUSOMERTID', 'INNER');
 $this->db->join('SALERDER AS sorder', 'sorder.ORDERID = job.ORDERID', 'INNER');
 $this->db->join('CUSTADDRESS AS address', 'address.ADDRID = sorder.DELADDRID', 'INNER');        
 $this->db->join('WORK2 AS job2', 'job2.JOBID = job.JOBID', 'LEFT');

 // THE BELOW LINE CAUSE ERROR DUE TO LOWER
 $this->db->join('SUBURBS AS suburb', 'suburb.LCNAME = lower_address', 'LEFT');

 $query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: @Parveen Kumar, I have added columns, Please have a look and suggest some solution.Since I have array of columns so I can't use the above scenario. Many Thanks

Comment: I also have tried columns as         $columns = [
            'job.JOBID AS Id', 'job.ORDERID AS orderID', 'suburb.LONGITUDE AS Longitude', 'suburb.LATITUDE AS Latitude', 'suburb.LCNAME', 'LOWER(address.TOWN)'
        ];                           but it also not worked for me.

Comment: @user6159419 Have you tried `LOWER(address.Town)` ?? Maybe the column name is mismatching

Comment: @PraveenKumar `TOWN` and `Town` are the same column. It would be different it we were talking about `TOWN` vs `"Town"`, unless codeigniter automatically quotes columns.

Comment: Yes I have tried it, column name is not mismatching. Let me try to generate the query as per marks advise. Maybe it help.

Comment: @user6159419 Yes try with `echo $this->db->last_query();` and run that query in phpmyadmin see the results for debugging

Comment: @PraveenKumar is there a function in CI to get end query text? Like your `last_query()` but without actual attempt to execute it before?

Comment: Oh, I found it, `get_compiled_select()` should show the text before execution. I still wonder why `join()` method does not have alias-enabled overload. But it might be not very necessary for programmic q constructors indeed. https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html